# What is the equivalent type of SQL Timestamp in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, type-conversion, timestamp

We have a recordversion column (Something like 0x00000000006EC935) of type timestamp in SQL. Want to have it as a string in c# code. What is equivalent type? How to convert?

Comment: The 'native' type for this would be `byte[]` . Why would you want a string?  No user will be able to make heads or tails of it.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @HenkHolterman to save it in a config record.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel SQL Server 2016

Comment: A timestamp is (should be) very volatile. It doesn't make too much sense to store that anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is none, timestamp [in SQL server is a row version and has nothing to do with time. The closest you get to it is a byte[8] array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017)

The problem is that you need to generate a unique number. You can create a threadsave counter that you increment and convert, however you could do that without bothering the to convert it to a byte array.

You can best leave it as a byte[]. [the current framework & EF maintain it like this to track concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency).

Answer (score 3):

You can map Timestamp type in sql to Byte[] in .net.

you can convert string rowVersion to byte[] and vise versa like this:

```
    // string rowVersion To Byte[]
    byte[] byt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strOriginal);

    // Byte[] rowVersion to string

    strModified = Convert.ToBase64String(byt);
```